# Ubuntu Gedit Text editor missing "undo last action" and "re do last action" arrows

Tags: gedit, text-editor

I used to have Ubuntu Gedit text editor Version 3.10.4, 
with a very nice toolbar, with

one icon with the shape of an arrow, dedicated to the 
"un-do last change" and

one icon with the shape of an arrow, dedicated to the 
"re-do last change"

Now i have latest 
Ubuntu version 18.04 LTS, 
kernel version 4.15.0-50-generic
Gedit Version 3.28.1

My problem, in new Gedit 3.28.1 
i didn't find the two arrow for quickly navigating back and forth 
in the change i made in the text file since last saving.

there is only a menu with the possibility of undo last minutes, but i need to go backward step by step per each change i made to the text file. like in most text editors and like it was in Gedit 3.10.4. change by change. not to go back few minutes. that's useless.

it was very nice in Gedit 3.10.4 version

i prefer Gedit and don't want any other editor.
i would like NOT to install an older version but i would like to have those arrows back in this latest version.
I would like not to use any shortcut keys like CTRL+whatever. I prefer those arrows.

any help appreciated.
Thanks.
Mario.

Comment: Gnome utilities have gone under some GUI "improvements" which are actually making their usage worse. Now in the version of Ubuntu 19.04 (Gedit --version 3.32) many commands and features are hidden behind some obscure menus or keyboard shortcuts. In my version (3.32) you can access the **Undo** and **Redo** commands by right clicking the mouse (besides Ctrl+Z for Undo and Shift+Ctrl+Z for Redo).